# Mobile on click dropdown menu not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown menu for the mobile version of my site, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Basically when I click on the dropdown menu image, the dropdown menu should appear.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfvjv184/

Included files:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="mobile_dropdown_menu_icon">
    <img class="mobilemenuicon" src="resources/mobilemenuicon.png" />
</div>

<div class="mobile_dropdown_menu">

</div>
```

CSS

```
    .mobile_dropdown_menu_icon {
        display:none;
    }

    .mobile_dropdown_menu {
        display:none;
    }

@media(max-device-width:500px) {

    .mobile_dropdown_menu_icon {
            display: block;
            float:right;
        }

    .mobilemenuicon {
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
            margin-top:10px;
            margin-right:20px;
        }

    .mobile_dropdown_menu {
            background-color: red;
            height:400px;
            width:100%;
        }

}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mobile_dropdown_menu_icon').on("click" function() {
        $('mobile_dropdown_menu').css("display", "block");

    });   
});
```

Any reason this is not working? I click the icon that should display the mobile_dropdown_menu but it does not work with this code.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or provide a link to the site?

Comment: @SamuelGoodell just added one to post

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$('mobile_dropdown_menu').css("display", "block");
```

...is missing a period in front of `mobile_dropdown_menu`.